# Allocation in function, unusable in main

Tags: c, function, malloc

I am trying to allocate space and put in file data in my function for my array of char arrays pointer in main. I get a segmentation fault when I run the program. Can anyone tell me why?

datawords[0] is printed correctly in the function.

This is my function:

```
void database_extract (char **data_words) {
FILE *f_data;
f_data = fopen("database.txt","r");     
struct stat st;
stat("database.txt", &st);
data_words = (char **)malloc(st.st_size * sizeof(char));
if (data_words == NULL) {
  printf("No room\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
data_words[0] = "test";
printf("%s",data_words[0]);
}
```

This is my main:

```
int main () {       
char **data_words;
database_extract (data_words);
printf("%s",data_words[0]);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's in "database.txt"?

Comment: Just a few strings of text seperated by whitespace. I don't actually use it for anything here. should have deleted it in this example. the size of it is 57 FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass to the function a pointer to the data_words array in order to use the allocation in the main.

try this:

```
void database_extract (char ***data_words) {
FILE *f_data;
f_data = fopen("database.txt","r");     
struct stat st;
stat("database.txt", &st);
*data_words = (char **)malloc(st.st_size * sizeof(char));
if (data_words == NULL) {
    printf("No room\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
data_words[0] = "test";
printf("%s",data_words[0]);
```

}

and in the main:

```
int main () {       
char **data_words;
database_extract (&data_words);
printf("%s",data_words[0]);
```

}

I am not sure if I got all the * right it gets me confused sometimes but the idea is to pass a pointer to the function.

Comment: Why `(char **)` cast and why `* sizeof(char)`?

Comment: I read somewhere that sizes of char can differ like size of int for instance can. Don't know if it is correct.

Comment: data_words[0] = "test" --> *data_words[0] = "test" was necesarry, but then it was correct :) thank you

Comment: "sizeof(char)" should be "sizeof(char*)"

Answer (score 2):

When you want something to be initialized by a function you need to use a `&` on the function call and one extra `*` in the function signature

```
void database_extract (char ***data_words) {
```

which is matched by

```
database_extract (&data_words);
```